# File input change event return me always a nil object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm using Jansy Boostrap [File Input](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask) and I'm trying to recover the src attribute when I change the image.

I'm using this script:

```
$(".fileinput").on "change", (e, files) ->
    source_image = $('.fileinput-preview img').prop('src')
    alert source_image
    $('.jcrop-box').each.attr('src', source_image)
```

My source_image is always nil. 
Maybe I have to set a delay?

Comment: I believe you are missing some brackets. Have you studied the syntax of Javascript in general?

Comment: @LajosArpad is Coffeescript. BTW I solved adding a delay. The input plugin need some millisecond to load the preview.

Answer (score 0):

I must add a delay!

Now it works:

```
timer = undefined
  delay = 600 # 0.5 seconds delay after last input
  $("#content_main_image").on "change", (e, files) ->
    window.clearTimeout timer
    timer = window.setTimeout(->
      source_image = $('.fileinput-preview img').prop('src')
      $('.jcrop-box').attr('src', source_image)
      $('.jcrop-holder').find('img').attr('src', source_image)

    , delay)
```